# Spinner in action bar: NullPointerException on setAdapter (Android - Java)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, spinner

I'm trying to put image + text inside a Spinner, but I have a NullPointerException on setAdapter.
It's all the afternoon I'm trying to fix that, but I can't figure out where is the problem.
Help will be very much appreciated! Here is the code:

res/menu/main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
   android:id="@+id/action_bar_main"
   android:title="@string/action_bar_main_add"
   android:showAsAction="always|withText"
   android:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar_main"       
   />
</menu>
```

res/layout/action_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dip">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerActionBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnActionBarMainAdd"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action_bar_main_add"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/plus_32x32"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp" 
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

res/layout/action_bar_spinner_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgSpinnerActionBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtSpinnerActionBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

src/package/Events.java

```
public class Events extends Activity {
final String[] spinnerCategories = {
        "Events", 
        "Calendar", 
        "Map", 
        "Notes",
        "Metronome",
        "Gallery", 
        "Pay",
        "Recorder",
        "Tuner"};

 final Integer[] spinnerImages = {
        R.drawable.pen_32x32,
        R.drawable.calendar_32x32,
        R.drawable.map_pin_20x32,
        R.drawable.document_24x32,
        R.drawable.equalizer_32x32,
        R.drawable.camera_32x32,
        R.drawable.money_48x48,
        R.drawable.note_48x48 };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("DEBUG","--> Entrato in Events.onCreate()");

    // ACTIONBAR: Customizza lo Spinner aggiungendo immagine + testo
    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerActionBar);
    CustomSpinnerAdapter adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.action_bar_spinner_row, spinnerCategories, spinnerImages);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter); 

    Log.d("DEBUG","<-- Uscendo da Events.onCreate()");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // ACTIONBAR: Nasconde il titolo e l'icona
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    // ACTIONBAR: Aggiunge oggetti all'actionbar, se è presente
    MenuInflater mMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    mMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}
}
```

src/package/CustomSpinnerAdapter.java

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

String[] spinnerCategories;     
Integer[] spinnerImages;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        String[] spinnerCategories, Integer[] spinnerImages) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, spinnerCategories);

    Log.d("DEBUG","--> Entrato nel costruttore di CustomSpinnerAdapter");        

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.spinnerCategories = spinnerCategories.clone();
    this.spinnerImages = spinnerImages.clone();

    Log.d("DEBUG","<-- Uscendo dal costruttore di CustomSpinnerAdapter");
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Log.d("DEBUG","--> Entrato in CustomSpinnerAdapter.getCustomView()");

    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_spinner_row, parent, false);

    TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtSpinnerActionBar);
    label.setText(spinnerCategories[position]);

    ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgSpinnerActionBar);
    icon.setImageResource(spinnerImages[position]);

    Log.d("DEBUG","<-- Uscendo da CustomSpinnerAdapter.getCustomView()");

    return row;
}    
}
```

**EDIT:**  I forgot to post the console output:

```
04-17 20:10:11.414: I/Process(22701): Sending signal. PID: 22701 SIG: 9
04-17 20:10:43.264: E/Trace(22838): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-17 20:10:43.314: D/DEBUG(22838): --> Entrato in Events.onCreate()
04-17 20:10:43.324: D/DEBUG(22838): --> Entrato nel costruttore di CustomSpinnerAdapter
04-17 20:10:43.324: D/DEBUG(22838): <-- Uscendo dal costruttore di CustomSpinnerAdapter
04-17 20:10:43.324: D/AndroidRuntime(22838): Shutting down VM
04-17 20:10:43.324: W/dalvikvm(22838): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415d5930)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.romagnoli.andrea.myrehearsals/it.romagnoli.andrea.myrehearsals.Events}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at it.romagnoli.andrea.myrehearsals.Events.onCreate(Events.java:43)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-17 20:10:43.324: E/AndroidRuntime(22838):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your logcat trace

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` I believe you need the layout with the `spinnerActionBar` element.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. If i put a comment on those three rows: Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerActionBar);
    CustomSpinnerAdapter adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.action_bar_spinner_row, spinnerCategories, spinnerImages);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);  the program runs, but with the spinner is empty (obviously). So the problem is something with the adapter?

Comment: remove generic argument for your ArrayAdapter i.e `ArrayAdapter<String>` remove `<String>` and also assign values directly instead of cloning

Comment: This is the direction but it still doesn't work. Looking into logcat I get like 50 access to getCustomView() and then an ArrayOutOfBoundsException (lenght=8; index=8) in CustomSpinnerAdapter:51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,**

Remove generic argument for your `ArrayAdapter` i.e `ArrayAdapter<String>` remove `<String>` and also assign values directly instead of cloning

**second,**

your `spinnerCategories`  has `9` elements, where as your `spinnerImages` have `8`, so adapter will take the length of `9`, when you are trying to read value of `8` index you will get

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

So `remove` one element from `spinnerCategories` or `add` one image to `spinnerImages`

Comment: Oh my god! It was a so a stupid mistake! Thank you very much, I was getting mad. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want spinner in action bar with action layout, You need to read Spinner in onCreateOptionsMenu.

Could be something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.action_bar_main).getActionView();

    Spinner spinner= ( Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerActionBar);
}
```

Look at this [Sample](https://github.com/TitusAbhi/ActionbarActionView)